# Dynamic column names in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have imported an excel file for creating a PBI report. In this excel, there is a cell which contains a date. I want to create columns on the basis of this cell.

Like if the cell contains 01/04/2017 then I would like to generate column names like Apr-17, May-17, ..., Dec-17, Jan-18,..., Mar-18.

If there any way to do this?
[image: Table structure]

Comment: From what you described it sounds like you're doing it wrong. Can you post a minimal example of your excel? And perhaps what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @user5226582 I have updated the question description with an image.

Comment: And what do you want to do with this data?

Comment: I just want to have the name of these columns dynamic, like if the date is 1 April 2017 then it should be Apr-17 to Mar-18, if the date is 1 April 2018 then it should be Apr-18 to Mar-19.

Comment: I'm not just being nosy, this sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just create a step by step procedure in edit query to pivot the table.
First you'd only get distinct values, then pivot and then promote to headers.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: Do you have one column with all the dates?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a column per month.

1) Create a query to import your file

[image]

2) In Query Editor, select the query, then "Transform" -> "Use First Row As Headers"

[image]

3) "Transform" -> "Unpivot Columns"

[image]

4) Rename columns as desired

[image]

Now you have a table in a comparable/filterable/queryable form. You didn't specify what you need it for but having a column per month won't work well (for various reasons). PowerBi doesn't work quite like excel.

If you really wanted a column per month, you could stop at step 2) but I would advise against it.